# Android: Layout is broken after return from fullscreen activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm developing an application which looks like a launcher but for books.

On main Activity I have book images and I can open them in specific reader application by tap. It works fine.

But when I go back from reader application I have a broken layout, upside of activity covered by a status bar. If I open the reader application one more time and return to main Activity again - all fine!

This is the code I use for open book with intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Uri bookFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(book.getFilePath()));
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(bookFileUri.toString());
String mimeType = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

intent.setDataAndType(bookFileUri, mimeType);

try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Log.d("Onyx", ex.getMessage());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.error_opening_book_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

[and after **first** time when i'm got back, i see this (look to top of activity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8eML.jpg)

How it can be fixed?

Comment: do you have implemented `onPause()` or `onResume()`

Comment: i didn't implemented it

Comment: is the layout inflated in `onCreate()` or procedurally generated?

Comment: it's inflated in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing views in OnResume(). When you press back then onCreate() is not called.

Comment: Please paste full code nd xml file of main activity